# CSS attribute select when any string

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute

I have a data attribute `data-modals`. I would like to target this with CSS when the property has a value. I don't mind what the value is.

I can find guides for selecting when the attribute exists, or specific values, but not for 'any' value - the equivalent of '*'.

ie.

`<element data-modals="" />` should not be targeted

`<element data-modals="any text" />` should be targeted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the **CSS Attribute Selector** like this:

```
element[data-modals]:not([data-modals=""]) {
  color: red;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
p[data-modals]:not([data-modals=""]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p data-modals="">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, fugit.
</p>

<p data-modals="any text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, fugit.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, fugit.
</p>
```

---

**Some useful links:**

- [Documentaion of Attribute selectors: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [Documentaion of Attribute selectors: W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)
- [Documentaion of :not(): MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Thanks, but I think you've misunderstood. I want to select regardless of the attribute value.
In your example, all of the `<p />` have the `data-modals` attribute. Some will have random values. I want to select those with a value, regardless of the value

Comment: Thanks, still not quite there as all of my elements have the `data-modals` attribute. I only want to select those with a value

Comment: @Jamie I have changed the answer, now it works as you told!

Comment: (This answered a previous version of your answer)
Unfortunately not. At the moment I will end up with a string containing any one of "search menu social login".
I can change the underlying login to add a prefix `modal-`. I can then use `[data-modals*="modal-"]`

Comment: @Jamie Now it is working... it is ignoring `data-modals=""` and working with `data-modals="any text"`

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I like the use of `:not`, it's something that I've `:not` got my head into doing yet. (and yes, the pun was absolutely intended!)